# Trouble with using UNICODE symbols in Java

Tags: java, unicode

welcome everyone as this is my first post here.
I have recently started programming in Java and I have a little problem.

I am trying to use "Almost equals to" symbol (\u2248) in my program, but it shows only "?"
However, some of the symbol, math category can be used, "+" for example.

Is there any library I should download of a file that needs to be included? Thanks for help.

Comment: It could be an issue with character encoding or your font (or both). Do you know what encoding is used?

Comment: Are you writing to the console? (default `System.out`) The Windows-Console for example does not support Unicode characters

Comment: Can you show us an snippet of the code you are using?

Comment: I was trying to show it int the console by using the system.out class:

System.out.println("\u2248"); Should it work?

Answer (score 1):

It's not just you or java, it takes fonts and other files in you system, check this out :
http://www.multilingual.com/articleDetail.php?id=540